# show that , There are One-to-one correspondence Between Algebras and Partitions.

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

definition
A family $\mathcal A$ ia said to be an algebra if:
(a) $\Omega \in \mathcal A;$ $\Omega$ is total set
(b) $E \in \mathcal A \Rightarrow E^c \in \mathcal A$
(c)$E,F \in \mathcal A \Rightarrow E\cup F \in\mathcal A $

show that , There are One-to-one correspondence Between Algebras and Partitions.
Thanks for any hints

Comment: @copper.hat hello.if it is possible for you Please help me to solve this problem.thanks

Comment: @Asaf Karagila
hello.if it is possible for you Please help me to solve this problem.thanks